# Use Perl modules from Linux server on Windows

Tags: linux, perl

How can I use modules that are installed on a Linux server, from Windows?
I tried using `lib` and `BEGIN` to add modules path to `@INC`,
but it throws an error

> can't locate xyz.pm in @INC

These modules are not available on CPAN or PPM.
Here is my code:

```perl
use strict;
system ("cls");
BEGIN { unshift(@INC, "/usr/local/lib/perl/File") } # path for modules on linux server
use File::article; # module on linux server
use Cwd;
use File::Path;
use Net::FTP;
use Net::SSH::W32Perl;
use Net::Telnet;

my $host;
my $login;
my $password;

$host = "abc.xyz.com";
$login = "login";
$password = "password";
```

Comment: You have a bunch of code relating to SSH there. Are you asking how you can remotely load a module using SSH?

Comment: This makes me think of Object::Remote, but the other way around.

Comment: What's the actual message you got, and what's the full path to the file?

Comment: Check out [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton). It can bundle your app with all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here.

Firstly, it sounds like you're trying to load modules from a remote system. The easiest way to to this would be to mount the remote filesystem on your local system (using NFS or something like that). The remote filesystem would then have a path on your local system which you could put into `@INC`. Another option would be to use something like [Object::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Remote), but I think that might be rather difficult to get right.

Your second problem is that you want to use modules that were built for a Linux system on a Windows system. Now, most Perl modules are written in pure Perl which means that they are largely cross-platform. But some of modules have a component which needs to be compiled. These cannot be used on a platform other than the one that they were built for. We know nothing about your modules, so we can't know whether this is going to be a problem for you.

But I think that, all in all, you're going about solving this problem the wrong way. A much better solution would be to install these modules on your local Windows system. You say that they aren't available on PPM of CPAN. In that case, you'll need to find out where they come from (perhaps by reading the documentation) and see if you can find instructions for installing them on Windows. At a pinch, if they are pure Perl modules, this might be a simple as copying them to the correct module library directory.

One last note. Your line:

```
BEGIN { unshift(@INC, "/usr/local/lib/perl/File") }
```

Is more usually (and more maintainably) written as:

```
use lib '/usr/local/lib/perl/File';
```

(This is just good practice - it still won't work for the reasons explained above.)

**Update:** I've just noticed another problem. You are adding the path `/usr/local/lib/perl/File` to `@INC` and then loading a module called `File::article`. I'm guessing that the file you're trying to load is `/usr/local/lib/perl/File/article.pm`, in which case you have an extra "File" on the end of the library path. It should be just:

```
use lib '/usr/local/lib/perl/';
```

But this still won't work because your Windows machine knows nothing about this directory.